# VS Code automatically activating virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was at first prompted to enter the virtual environment being used in my project by vs-code, and so I accepted.

Even though I'm now in a different project folder, it still tries to enter the non-existent virtual environment automatically (I clicked `Don't show me again` on the popup so it doesn't ask anymore). When I run a python program, the terminal runs the following command:

`PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> & "c:/filepath/virtual_env/Scripts/Activate.ps1"`

and then I recieve this error:

```
& : File c:\filepath\virtual_env\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "c:/filepath ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

How can I disable automatically activating the virtual environment?

Comment: did you read the page referenced in the error message? seems all the info you need is right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`venv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) have a note about how to change your execution policy: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` (requires Python 3.8, otherwise you need to use a different execution policy).

As for turning off automatic environment activation, `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` will do it as covered by the [environments docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for the Python extension point out.